# Public transport in Inari?

Tags: public-transport, finland

Is there any public transport in the municipality of Inari, Finland?

I am interested in taxis or buses.

Answer (score 6):

There are at least two taxi services. [One](https://www.inarisaariselka.fi/company/kuukkeli-taxi-inari-saariselka-central-rental-company/) says:

> Kuukkel Taxis serve all kind of transportion services. We have two spacious taxis, each of which can accommodate 8 passengers. A covered trailer for transporting goods is available additionally, if required. From us you can get Airport transfers, local transfers: to all accommodation destinations, Saariselkä village, Laanila, Kiilopää, Inari, Ivalo, Norway, Rovaniemi, Kittilä, etc.

The [other](https://www.inarisaariselka.fi/company/kuukkeli-taxi-inari-saariselka-central-rental-company/) is smaller, appearing to have only one vehicle:

> Taxi Briitta Pajari offers professional and always friendly service for travellers, groups and companies. High-standard 1+8 seater takes you safely where ever you need to go – airport or arctic adventures! Order the taxi at...

From the URL text, they might also each be willing to rent you their taxi for a while. There doesn't appear to be any government operated buses within the village or anything like that.

Comment: The actual village of Inari is tiny and easily walkable.  The municipality of Inari is immense (17,700 sq.km) and virtually uninhabited.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of buses running along the E75. There are various departures each day but none operate on a turn up and go frequency. Times and fares can be checked (and tickets purchased) at: https://www.matkahuolto.fi/

Times are also available on Google Maps: https://maps.app.goo.gl/QSGKvy8RxZD71gAp8

Answer (score 3):

Inari is both a municipality (rather large one, over 100km across) and a village (small, maybe 1km across) in the approximate centre of the earlier.

The north of Finland is very sparsely populated, there is regular bus service on the main road, but it may very well be only 1 bus per day in the direction you are travelling.

The village you can just walk across :)

Best resource: https://www.inari.fi/fi/matkailu/liikenneyhteydet.html (google-translate it).

Comment: Is this the English version of the page you linked? https://www.inari.fi/en/for-travellers-2/how-to-get-here.html

Comment: it's not bad, but the page in Finnish has a little more information, and might be more up to date.